# Generating coefficients for SERIESSUM formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm modelling a cash collection spreadsheet where a company sells products each week and wants to collect cash over a number of weeks (*n*; between 42 and 336 weeks).

Assuming *n* is ≤ 52:

To calculate the cash collections and also factor in weekly sales growth, I have used the SERIESSUM formula as follows: `SERIESSUM((1+growth rate),(52-n),1,ROW(INDIRECT(D29&":"&D30)))*250`. 250 is projected first week sales.

Cell D29 is 0 and D30 is *n*-1. What I'm trying to achieve is to list all numbers from 0 to *n*-1 as coefficients in the SERIESSUM formula. However, I'm getting a `#REF` error. Can anyone please locate what I'm doing wrong here?

The formula works fine when I manually list the numbers from 1 to *n*-1 in rows and refer as follows: `SERIESSUM((1+growth rate),(52-n),1,A2:A53)*250`. However, the manual nature means that if the number of weeks is changed (i.e., amount per week increases/reduces), the manual bit has to be re-done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INDIRECT(D29&":"&D30)`,
with `D29` = 0 and `D30` = 51, evaluates to `INDIRECT("0:51")`,
which is an error ***because there is no row 0.*** 
To generate the constant array `{0,1,2,…,49,50,51}` programmatically,
use `ROW(INDIRECT("1:52"))-1`.

Comment: Thanks Scott. How about if I want to generate the array in descending order i.e {51, 50, 49, ....2, 1, 0}? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Pls scratch. Now done. Just used `ABS(ROW(INDIRECT("1:52"))-52)`. Thank you.